# Restful Web Services - Maintaining Foreign Keys

Tags: java, mysql, sql, rest, relational-database

Am I misunderstanding a basic concept of Restful web services? I have an Android app that I am trying to use a Restful PUT. Two Mysql tables Country and StateProvince with countryId a foreign key on StateProvince table.

If I try to do a PUT to StateProvince using the following

`<StateProvince><stateName>Victoria</stateName><countryId>1</countryId></StateProvince>`

I get the error below. Am I misunderstanding a basic concept regarding foreign keys and Rest?

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseExcepti on
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityCons traintViolationException: Column 'country_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO state_province (state_id, state_name, country_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.pezoot.models.StateProvince[ stateId=2 ])
```

Comment: This is a SQL/database problem, and it has nothing to do with REST at all.

Comment: Does your PUT request body have a country_id in it?  A valid country_id?  Does your server side code handle the country id correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: country_id is null, so this looks like a database/persistence issue. You probably didn't *set* the Country for the StateProvince (or add the StateProvince to the Country - haven't seen your code so I don't know how you're mapping things).

Long Answer:

Why is there an database identifier coming in as part of your HTTP request?

You need to start thinking in terms of URIs and resources - your StateProvince representation should have some kind of *link* that relates to a country at a particular URI (e.g. `<link rel="country" href="/country/1" />` and in your resource class that handles the PUT verb, you need to be able to conver that URI in to a domain object, an entity (as it seems you're using EclipseLink) which you can use some setter method or something on to establish the database relation. **The REST relationship and the database relationship are fundamentally different.**

It takes practice and careful thinking to handle what seems like a simple concept (HTTP verbage) against your persistence unit. Something that seems straightforward like `PUT` has nontrivial processing required in order to make it work as REST would expect.

It is tempting to use database identifiers in URIs because it is easy (especially if you use subresources that just happen to magically know who their parent is: e.g. country/1/stateprovince/2) but you have to step back and ask yourself, is it country/1 or is it country/usa - you also have to ask yourself, is the country and state/province really an entity? or is it just a value object? Do you *really* intend to PUT a State/Province in its entirety?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

Once again (unsurprisingly) it appears to be a syntax error. When I used the following:

```
<stateProvince> 
       <countryId> 
           <countryId>1</countryId> 
      </countryId> 
       <stateName>New South Wales</stateName> </stateProvince>
```

Hey presto it works. I had failed to embed the countryId as shown above previously (see old code below)

```
<stateProvince> 
       <countryId>1</countryId> 
       <stateName>New South Wales</stateName> </stateProvince>
```

And thanks Doug - your response is the sort of insight I am seeking. I dont believe I have quite wrapped my head around the use of links as you describe - but I will investigate further now